# Actual baud rate of UNO R3 Firmata protocol

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, baud-rate, firmata

Probably a silly question. But the Internet is confusing me.
The Firmata website says the default baud rate is 57600. But AFAIK, the baud rate set for UNO R3 is 9600(In Windows device manager, it say so). I'm making the Firmata client program and have to set the baud rate. I'm confused whether it's similar to the serial protocol or not.
[Using the StandardFirmata sketch]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The baud rate is whatever the program opening the port requests it to be. The stuff in the device manager is only the default used if nothing else is specified when the port is opened.

And the Firmata protocol just squirts bytes over serial. It's based upon the MIDI protocol, which is just serial.

Comment: So clearly I should declare as 9600?

Comment: If the sketch you are running has the baud set to 57600 then the program you use to communicate with your sketch has to be set to 57600. Ignore device manager. It's completely irrelevant.